# Can I customize the bottom help lines in Nano Editor?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, nano

Can I choose which shortcuts appear in the bottom two lines from the nano editor?

so instead of the default ones, I may `Go to line and column number` and `Mark text at the cursor position` instead of `Justify the current paragraph` and `Insert another file into the current one`

if I can, how do I do it? I couldn't fine any info on google or anywhere

Comment: I couldn't find anything either; I fear you'd need to make changes in the [source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src) directly and compile your own version of `nano` for that.

Comment: True. Nano is a very simple editor, so the shown commands can't be altered. However, you can tweak the keybindings to your own liking, and if you're familiar with the keybindings you should have less need for the command bar.

Answer (score 3):

The shortcuts are hard coded so they cannot be changed without modifying the source code. You can find some of them spread throughout the [global.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/src/global.c) file.

If you want to hide the shortcuts you can start nano with the `nano -x` flag or add `set nohelp` to your `~/.nanorc` file.